# Add a nested collection to a Rabl of the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

I have a rabl:

```
collection @posts.sort_by { |p| p["title"] }
attributes :id, :name, :title
```

which gives me a json result like this:

```
[{ "id":9, "name":"whatever", "title":"whatever" }]
```

Now I'd also like to add to each item in my collection a 'sub-collection' of related posts, with the same attributes -- like this:

```
[{ "id":9, "name":"Sports", "title":"whatever", 
  "related_posts": [
    { "id":10, "name":"Other sports", "title":"whatever" }
  ] 
}]
```

Assuming my Post model already has a related_posts attribute, how can I get this in there?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
collection @posts.sort_by { |p| p["title"] }
attributes :id, :name, :title
child(:related_posts) { attributes :id, :name, :title }
```

Hope it helps.